# Merge Two Sorted LinkedLists in Java (using the default LinkedList class, not custom class)

Tags: java, list, merge, linked-list, singly-linked-list

So I'm trying to solve the Leetcode problem (#21) of merging two sorted lists, however I'm trying to do it using the standard LinkedList class in Java (the Leetcode problem uses a custom 'ListNode' class. Here's an elegant solution using the ListNode class:

```
public class Solution {
public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {

    ListNode head = new ListNode(0);
    ListNode tail = head;
    while(l1 != null && l2 != null) {
        if (l1.val <= l2.val) {
            tail.next = l1;
            l1 = l1.next;
        } else {
            tail.next = l2;
            l2 = l2.next;
        }
        tail = tail.next;
    }
    
    if (l1 != null) {
        tail.next = l1;
    } else if (l2 != null) {
        tail.next = l2;
    }
    
    return head.next;
}
```

Which I understand just fine, however if I'm using the LinkedList class, what would I use in place of `l1.val` or `l2.val`? It seems LinkedList doesn't have a function for retrieving the current node value, but surely there's a way to do this? It seems like it would be very standard for a List.

Comment: [`l1.get(0)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#get(int))?

Answer (score 1):

The `LinkedList` class does not give you access to nodes, just to values. So there is never a property access like `l1.val`, nor `l1.next`. One way to traverse a linked list instance, is to create an iterator using the `listIterator` method. This iterator does not yield nodes, but values.

Although the first loop can be closely approached using the `LinkedList` class, one cannot do the step that is done in your last `if...else` block: you'll have to add each value of the remaining list to the result list -- there is no way to link the tail of the result list with another list.

Here is how you could do it with iterators. Note that I have made the `while` condition a logical OR condition instead of an AND condition, so to deal with the issue mentioned in the above paragraph:

```
public LinkedList<Integer> mergeTwoLists(LinkedList<Integer> l1, LinkedList<Integer> l2) {
    LinkedList<Integer> result = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    ListIterator<Integer> iter1 = l1.listIterator();
    ListIterator<Integer> iter2 = l2.listIterator();
    Integer value1 = iter1.hasNext() ? iter1.next() : null;
    Integer value2 = iter2.hasNext() ? iter2.next() : null;
    while (value1 != null || value2 != null) {
        if (value2 == null || value1 != null && value1 <= value2) {
            result.add(value1);
            value1 = iter1.hasNext() ? iter1.next() : null;
        } else {
            result.add(value2);
            value2 = iter2.hasNext() ? iter2.next() : null;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Did this answer your question? Can you give some feed-back?